# Symfony Routing in PHP

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to set a default value for city to "ABC", how can I do that in this code? Also, are there any examples for me to add multiple routes to this collection?

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();

$collection->add('hello_world_first_homepage', new Route('/weather/{city}', array(
    '_controller' => 'HelloWorldFirstBundle:Default:index',
)));

return $collection;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.html), the [Route](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.html) constructor take as a second parameter an [array of default values](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.html#method___construct).

You can then add `'city' => "ABC'` to the array you're using to intitialize your new route.